# Is PHP & MySQL allowed in developing android apps?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I would like to make an additional app to my website - is based on PHP & MySQL. Website should be shown in the app. So I would like to ask if PHP & MySQL are allowed in developing android apps? Just to shorten the time spent on programming the app and reduce or skip JS or other languages.

Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: no this can't happen you could host php and mysql app on android but cannot program android app on top of php andd mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You can not build and android app based on php and MySQl. PHP is a server side scripting langauge, while MySQL is a database management System. What you can is that you can provide APIs which may be used by your mobile application to get and post data.

Answer (score 0):

"Allowed"?

Well Android runs third party applications using Java. You can run more languages using the Android NDK, but the PHP+MySQL is not supposed to work on Android as it does on lets say Apache...

It's Android: a Java-based OS.

And I doubt you'll save time like that.
Make your website mobile-ready or build a regular Android (so Java) application is my adice.